# transfer event ID to triggered task in Windows

Tags: windows, events, triggers, taskscheduler, event-id

I have one particular system task in Windows (7 or XP, for example) with multiple triggers by various system events. Is it possible to transfer event ID to the task, that is triggered with this event? For example, the task runs a script. Can I pass ID of the event, that triggered this task, to the script as command line parameter (or some other way)? Or can I pass other attributes of the event to the script (in order to parse the event with the script)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/task-scheduler-event-log-trigger-include-event-data-in-mail/) helped me to solve the issue perfectly. That was I actually searched: transferring any event attribute to triggered task as parameter, and the article describes it.